# Makefile for all files

Tags: c++, makefile

How I can write makefile for my structure:

```
/ --
   /bin
   /out
   /src --
        /dir1
        /dir2
        ...
        /dirN
   main.cpp
```

I want:

- Compile all files recursively from /src directory
- All .out files to /out, without *src* directory structure
- Compile main.cpp with all .out files

I have both `.c` and `.cpp` files to compile and linking.

I tried:

```
${OBJ_DIR}/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $< -o $@ ${CFLAGS}
```

But I now don't know how I can make `all` rule...

Comment: have you tried cmake? http://www.cmake.org

Comment: +1 for CMake, it is an elegant solution for that kind of problem

Comment: @klm123 - hmm... but I can't find any good tutorial about it, I must first compile all files from /src to .o (g++ -c), and link all .o in one executable, with tons of libraries (like -lGL, -lpthread...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a Makefile that I whipped up which I use in a lot of my projects:

```
# Compiler
CC   = g++
OPTS = -std=c++11

# Project name
PROJECT = foo_example_program

# Libraries
LIBS = -lpthread
INCS = -I./src/include

SRCS = $(shell find src -name '*.cpp')
DIRS = $(shell find src -type d | sed 's/src/./g' ) 
OBJS = $(patsubst src/%.cpp,out/%.o,$(SRCS))

# Targets
$(PROJECT): buildrepo $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OPTS) $(OBJS) $(LIBS) $(INCS) -o $@

out/%.o: src/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(OPTS) -c $< $(INCS) -o $@

clean:
    rm $(PROJECT) out -Rf

buildrepo:
    mkdir -p out
    for dir in $(DIRS); do mkdir -p out/$$dir; done
```

NOTE: Thinking back, I remember why I replicated the src directory structure - that is, if two files were named the same thing in multiple directories, they would overwrite one another. One solution to this would be to add some type of identifier to each object file. For instance, a number at the end. When a duplicate object file is found, you could name the object files 'object.1.o' and 'object.2.o' or something.

Comment: This is not safe for parallel builds, unless you run `make buildrepo` by hand first before you start the build.  Also, the OP was looking for a solution which dumped all the object files in `out` directly, with no extra directory structure (so `src/foo/bar/biz.c` would be compiled into `out/biz.c`)

Comment: @MadScientist Aha, I modified it slightly to be able to set the object directory in a variable, but it still uses the src directory structure... I am curious about this myself, so I will try to figure that out as well.

EDIT: actually I just remembered that buildrepo is automatically called when you just run 'make'.

Comment: The directory structure is a cosmetic ;) Just all .o in one directory looks better

Comment: @aso I remember why I did it this way. My edit on the answer explains why.

Comment: @elimirks Your script didn't work, and I don't have enough knowledge to edit it correct.. :/ It's trying to compile main program (but generates invalid g++ line) first

Comment: @elimirks output error is about "g++ nothing to compile" because make creates wrong command (it tries compile $(PROJECT) first, not all objects)

Comment: @aso
Which version of gcc or make do you use? It should also show some output, could you gist that?

Comment: Ah! Jesteś z Polska? :D It seems as though I messed up the script by introducing variables within some of the operations. I manually wrote the 'out' directory in the newly modified version and it seems to work properly now.

Comment: Yes I'm from poland :D Very thanks for update, I made some changes and now works like a charm :)